# Choose 3 element out of 5 in CStringArray?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2013, mfc

In this code keepSelectedFiles have 5 text Files. I want to choose 3 of them and add into another array keepFiles. count is just a input from user. If user select 3 in text box then count is 3 any number etc.

```
for (int i = 0; i < keepSelectedFiles.GetSize(); i++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                keepFiles.RemoveAt(keepFiles.IsEmpty());
                keepFiles.Add(keepSelectedFiles[i]);
                testbox6.AddString(keepFiles[i]);
            }
        }
```

Please help me how i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way to do it (performance optimized):

```
if (count < 0)
  return; // error handling

if (count < keepSelectedFiles.GetSize())
{
  keepFiles.SetSize(count);
  for (int i=0; i<count; i++)
  {
      keepFiles[i] = keepSelectedFiles[i];
  }
}
else
{
    keepFiles.Copy(keepSelectedFiles);
}
```

Comment: Sir Excellent than you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Lets do it "on paper":

Lets say the you want to get the three first strings from `keepSelectedFiles` and add them to `keepFiles`, then you would

1. Get the first string in `keepSelectedFiles` and add to `keepFiles`
2. Get the second string in `keepSelectedFiles` and add to `keepFiles`
3. Get the third string in `keepSelectedFiles` and add to `keepFiles`

That's all.

To translate it to code, you make a single loop that will iterate three (`count`) times, from `0` to `2` (inclusive) and use that number as an index into `keepSelectedFiles`. So the resulting code will look like

```
for (int i = 0; i < count && i < keepSelectedFiles.GetSize(); ++i(
{
    keepFiles.Add(keepSelectedFiles[i]);
}
```

That's it.